# PayPal User to User Payment

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, payment, braintree

I am new to the PayPal API and can not seem to find what I am looking for. Say I have two users, UserA and UserB. Given that they both have PayPal accounts, I want to send money from UserA directly to UserB. Is this possible? If so, what is it called and where is the documentation for this API. Just for clarification, I want the transaction to be direct without any "middle man".

Answer (score 1):

Check the adaptative payments api 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

Comment: When I first visited this page it stated: Important: Adaptive Payments is now a limited release product. It is restricted to select partners for approved use cases and should not be used for new integrations without guidance from PayPal.

Comment: What does this exactly mean I do?

Comment: I'm not sure about, but this is part of their own api so i thinks there is no reason to don't implement it